# pdo redirection to another page

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have a registration form, login, home and user offline. I'm using the wamp server 2.5. login redirects user either to the home page or to the login page.

My problem is that offline everything works fine but online only registration form its working login does not redirect to home page.

Here is my connection to mysql code:

```
dbconfig.php

<?php

session_start();

$DB_host = "localhost:3306";
$DB_user = "cashgalo";
$DB_pass = "57121363RbK@*<R>";
$DB_name = "cashgalo_bill";

try
{
   $DB_con = new PDO("mysql:host={$DB_host};dbname{$DB_name}",$DB_user,$DB_pass);
 $DB_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); }
catch(PDOException $e)
{
 echo $e->getMessage();
```

}

```
include_once 'user.php';
$user = new USER($DB_con);
```

here is my index form where the user login after registration

```
index.php

<?php
require_once 'dbconfig.php';

if($user->is_loggedin()!="")
{
 $user->redirect('homee.php');
 }

 if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
 {
  $uname = $_POST['txt_uname_email'];
  $umail = $_POST['txt_uname_email'];
  $upass = $_POST['txt_password'];

   if($user->login($uname,$umail,$upass))
   {
    $user->redirect('home.php');
   }
   else
     {
         $error = "Wrong Details !";
      } 
     }
        ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Login : cleartuts</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"  />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"  />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="form-container">
    <form method="post">
        <h2>Sign in.</h2><hr />
        <?php
        if(isset($error))
        {
              ?>
              <div class="alert alert-danger">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> &nbsp; <?php echo $error; ?> !
              </div>
              <?php
        }
        ?>
        <div class="form-group">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt_uname_email" placeholder="Username or E mail ID" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
         <input type="password" class="form-control" name="txt_password" placeholder="Your Password" required />
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div><hr />
        <div class="form-group">
         <button type="submit" name="btn-login" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i>&nbsp;SIGN IN
            </button>
        </div>
        <br />
        <label>Don't have account yet ! <a href="sign-up.php">Sign Up</a></label>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

here is the password hashing code:

```
   password hash().php
   <?php

 $password = "123456";
 $hash = password_hash($passwod, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
 $hashed_password = "$2y$10$BBCpJxgPa8K.iw9ZporxzuW2Lt478RPUV/JFvKRHKzJhIwGhd1tpa";

 /*
 "123456" will become "$2y$10$BBCpJxgPa8K.iw9ZporxzuW2Lt478RPUV/JFvKRHKzJhIwGhd1tpa"
 */ 

?>
```

here is the verification password:

```
  password verify().php
  <?php

 $password = "123456";
 $hashed_password = "$2y$10$BBCpJxgPa8K.iw9ZporxzuW2Lt478RPUV/JFvKRHKzJhIwGhd1tpa";
 password_verify($password, $hashed_password);

 /*
  if the password match it will return true.
 */ 

?>
```

this is the user registration form

```
 sign-up.php
 <?php
  require_once 'dbconfig.php';

  if($user->is_loggedin()!="")
  {
  $user->redirect('dashboard.php');
  }

 if(isset($_POST['btn-signup']))
  {
  $uname = trim($_POST['txt_uname']);
  $umail = trim($_POST['txt_umail']);
  $upass = trim($_POST['txt_upass']); 

  if($uname=="") {
     $error[] = "provide username !"; 
     }
    else if($umail=="") {
      $error[] = "provide email id !"; 
    }
     else if(!filter_var($umail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $error[] = 'Please enter a valid email address !';
    }
     else if($upass=="") {
       $error[] = "provide password !";
     }
   else if(strlen($upass) < 6){
      $error[] = "Password must be atleast 6 characters"; 
   }
   else
    {
  try
  {
     $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT user_name,user_email FROM users  WHERE user_name=:uname OR user_email=:umail");
     $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname, ':umail'=>$umail));
     $row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

     if($row['user_name']==$uname) {
        $error[] = "sorry username already taken !";
     }
     else if($row['user_email']==$umail) {
        $error[] = "sorry email id already taken !";
     }
     else
     {
        if($user->register($fname,$lname,$uname,$umail,$upass)) 
        {
            $user->redirect('sign-up.php?joined');
        }
     }
 }
 catch(PDOException $e)
 {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
  } 
 }

  ?>
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Sign up : cleartuts</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"   type="text/css"  />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"  />
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="container">
    <div class="form-container">
    <form method="post">
        <h2>Sign up.</h2><hr />
        <?php
        if(isset($error))
        {
           foreach($error as $error)
           {
              ?>
              <div class="alert alert-danger">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> &nbsp; <?php echo $error; ?>
              </div>
              <?php
           }
        }
        else if(isset($_GET['joined']))
        {
             ?>
             <div class="alert alert-info">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i> &nbsp; Successfully registered <a href='index.php'>login</a> here
             </div>
             <?php
        }
        ?>
        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt_uname" placeholder="Enter Username" value="<?php if(isset($error)){echo $uname;}?>" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt_umail" placeholder="Enter E-Mail ID" value="<?php if(isset($error)){echo $umail;}?>" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
         <input type="password" class="form-control" name="txt_upass" placeholder="Enter Password" />
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div><hr />
        <div class="form-group">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" name="btn-signup">
             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-open-file"></i>&nbsp;SIGN UP
            </button>
        </div>
        <br />
        <label>have an account ! <a href="index.php">Sign In</a></label>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>

</body>
 </html>
```

this is my user php file

```
   user.php
   <?php
    class USER
  {
  private $db;

function __construct($DB_con)
{
  $this->db = $DB_con;
}

public function register($fname,$lname,$uname,$umail,$upass)
{
   try
   {
       $new_password = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

       $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(user_name,user_email,user_pass) 
                                                   VALUES(:uname, :umail, :upass)");

       $stmt->bindparam(":uname", $uname);
       $stmt->bindparam(":umail", $umail);
       $stmt->bindparam(":upass", $new_password);            
       $stmt->execute(); 

       return $stmt; 
   }
   catch(PDOException $e)
   {
       echo $e->getMessage();
      }    
      }

  public function login($uname,$umail,$upass)
     {
   try
   {
      $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name=:uname OR user_email=:umail LIMIT 1");
      $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname, ':umail'=>$umail));
      $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
      {
         if(password_verify($upass, $userRow['user_pass']))
         {
            $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['user_id'];
            return true;
         }
         else
         {
            return false;
         }
      }
   }
   catch(PDOException $e)
   {
       echo $e->getMessage();
   }
  }

   public function is_loggedin()
  {
  if(isset($_SESSION['user_session']))
  {
     return true;
  }
  }

    public function redirect($url)
  {
   header("Location: $url");
   }

  public function logout()
  {
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['user_session']);
    return true;
  }
 }
?>
```

this is my home page for the user

```
     <?php
  include_once 'dbconfig.php';
  if(!$user->is_loggedin())
  {
   $user->redirect('index.php');
    }
   $user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];
 $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=:user_id");
 $stmt->execute(array(":user_id"=>$user_id));
 $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"  />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"  />
  <title>welcome - <?php print($userRow['user_email']); ?></title>
  </head>

  <body>

  <div class="header">
 <div class="left">
 <label><a href="http://www.codingcage.com/">Coding Cage - Programming  Blog      </a></label>
 </div>
 <div class="right">
 <label><a href="logout.php?logout=true"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></i> logout</a></label>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
   welcome : <?php print($userRow['user_name']); ?>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Anyone can get your db access if they know domain/host name.

Comment: `$user->redirect('homee.php');` - `homee`?

Comment: No Mr Blue its home.php

Comment: you provide all this "Stuff" which has noting to do with the error, then you don't show us what `redirect()` does.  You have to call `exit` after a header redirect, you cannot output before calling header.  Those are the two rules.  We don't even know the name of these files, it's probably a casing issue because Linux is case sensitive and windows is not.  Basically you give us all this stuff to wade through and fail to give what we actually need.

Comment: ""password hashing""

Comment: At ArtisticPhoenix i do not get any error message it gets back to index.php

Comment: few things: mysql details change per location, so local + dev mysql details will be different (I noticed you specify a port - this port may change on your server) - also if you're developing on a Windows environment and testing on a Linux one, make sure your file names / table names are case-sensitive, Windows for some reasons opted to be case-insensitive, in Linux, index.php is a different file to Index.php - also and lastly, if it's a Linux environment, make sure your file permissions are correct (775 for directories and 664 for files) and that your user owns those files